# When to use bigger-than-usual delimiters?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I am having issues deciding whether I should use `\{left\{…\right\}`, `\{bigl\{…\bigr\}` or simply `{}`. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[]{mathtools,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,mathalfa} % Math Packages
\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath} % Best font ever.

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
    \delta_{\{d_\lambda^i\}}\\
    \delta_{\left\{d_\lambda^i\right\}}\\
    \delta_{\bigl\{d_\lambda^i\bigr\}}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Which generates the following output:

[image]

I have read a lot of posts on this site about when to use bigger-than-usual delimiters, but I can’t really figure out a general rule that works for my taste. So, two questions:

1. **Which of the three options of the MWE would you choose for my delta function?**
2. **What are your general rules for bigger-than-usual delimiters (if any)?**

Comment: (1) every time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. While I understand you’d use (1) for my delta function, what about general rules for big delimiters? Would you never use them? Would you only use them to enclose big operators, like `\sum`, `\prod` and such? Or only in some other cases?

Comment: @EoDmnFOr3q - One of the main *typographical* rules to always be aware of is that good typography is characterized by *good visual balance*. Of course, this criterion is aesthetic and hence unavoidably subjective. A rule of thumb: If the delimiters become so big as to make the stuff they enclose visually unimportant, the delimiters are "too big". In one of the math-y chapters of the TeXbook, Knuth deliberately contrasts `$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\right)$$` and `$$\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\biggr)$$`. The parentheses in the former example "look too big" -- and thus *are too big*.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then, I’ll typeset my documents as I see visually pleasing and will come back to this site to ask when in doubt, like I did today with my delta function.